Mars and Earth are at war because the men who live in space are semi-sterile and can't father daughters
I was sure the book was by Andre Norton, but I can't find it after 2 hours of Googling.   Mars and Earth are at war because the men who live in space are semi-sterile and can't father daughters.   Thus they raid Earth for young women and food supplies.   On a raid to Chicago, our hero is assigned to fly down to Earth in a small spaceship and kidnap a young woman from a huge public swimming pool in Chicago(?).   Her twin brother tries to rescue her and is also kidnapped.   Earth is fighting back for the first time and the invasion fleet is attacked for the first time, since Earthmen are terrified of space.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

TY for the tags.   I probably first read it as a teen in 1960-70's.  It was a hardback with a purple, grey and black cover showing the interior of a small spaceship.   I pretty sure the were a few black & white drawings as interior illustrations.

Your question has been closed as a duplicate. This is not a censure. You will still receive points for upvotes and people can comment (and you can accept the answer formally by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons). We just can't publish new answers now. Congratulations on finding your work!

This is probably Raiders from the Rings (1962) by Alan E. Nourse.
The Google Books blurb for the book reads:

A young adult novel in which the human race is divided into the Spacers and those who still remain on earth. There is a constant low-level war between the two groups, with the Spacers raiding earth for supplies and for women. The war turns hot in the book and three teenagers, one Spacer and two from Earth, must find a way to bring peace.

A review on Goodreads tells a bit more:

A generation ago wars on earth split humanity into the Spacer colonies on Mars and the Asteroid Rigns and Earth . The hatreds for this war are not permitted to cool. Earth will not permit Spacers to trade freely, so the Spacers must raid Earth for thier own continued survival.
Young Ben Trefon, on his first raid, finds himself seperated from his fleet, with two Earth prisoners --Tom and Joyce Barron. Ben heads for his family home of Mars, to find that a first strike by the Earth Fleet has destoryed his home.
Previously, there has been no contact between the two sides. In a great scene, Ben hears from Tom and Joyce what is "common knowedge" about Spacers and his skin crawls. But his prisoners are also shocked about what Spacers "know" about Earthmen.


YES That's it   TY SO much!

@Kathy: You can click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept.

When I was younger, I sometimes confused Andre Norton and Alan Nourse because both had the initials A. N.
